# CSS: Centering text under a d3 slider on browser resize

Tags: html, css, d3.js

I can't seem to center "Delta Value: [weight-threshold]" correctly underneath a d3 slider on browser re-size. I would also like for both the "Delta Value" and the output for "weight-threshold" to remain on the same line. The output is a number value like "0.0006126." I've linked a jsfiddle for viewing.

```
#subtext, #weight-threshold {
text-align: center;
font-size: 13px;
}

#deltval {

padding-top: 7.5px;
position:fixed;
margin-right:40%;
margin-left:40%;
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

http://jsfiddle.net/Y3v9h/

Answer (score 0):

Correct:

```
#subtext, #weight-threshold {
font-size: 13px;
}
#deltval {
text-align:center;
padding-top: 7.5px;
}
```

Remove:

```
position:fixed;
margin-right:40%;
margin-left:40%;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CvR2u/